# Why does my HTML5 canvas render smaller than it should?

Tags: html, canvas

I'm mucking around with the `canvas` element and drawing, and a simple rectangle renders fewer pixels than it should. I can't figure out why - happens in the latest Firefox, Safari and Mobile Safari browsers. I would expect this to fill the entire canvas.

[image: screenshot]

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="draw" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #f00;"
onClick="doDraw(event)">
</canvas>
<script>
function doDraw(ev) {
    console.log(ev.clientX,ev.clientY);
    var el = document.getElementById('draw');
    var ctx = el.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<canvas id="draw" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid #f00;"
onClick="doDraw(event)">
```

needs to be

```
<canvas id="draw" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #f00;"
onClick="doDraw(event)">
```

you are modifying the style of the container, not the container. If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeesh, just when I got used to always using the style attribute... Thanks